# Epel repository not found in repolist after installation

Tags: centos, repository

On centos 6 I successfully install epel-release but the repos do not appear in my list.

Could someone please help?

```
[root@rhine ~]# yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
Package epel-release-6-8.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@rhine ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
repo id                      repo name         status
base                         CentOS-6 - Base   6,713
extras                       CentOS-6 - Extras    47
newrelic                     New Relic packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                  228
nginx                        nginx repo          186
percona-release-noarch       Percona Original release/noarch YUM repository                       55
percona-release-x86_64       Percona Original release/x86_64 YUM repository                      983
remi-safe                    Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64        2,906
updates                      CentOS-6 - Updates  987
repolist: 12,105
[root@rhine ~]# ls /etc/yum.repos.d
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Gluster-3.8.repo.rpmsave  city-fan.repo  percona-original-release.repo  remi-glpi93.repo  remi-php70.repo  remi-php73.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Media.repo                newrelic.repo  remi-glpi91.repo               remi-glpi94.repo  remi-php71.repo  remi.repo
CentOS-fasttrack.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo                nginx.repo     remi-glpi92.repo               remi-php54.repo   remi-php72.repo  remi-safe.repo
```

Comment: Please do `yum update` and then check again `rpm -qa | grep epel` and ` yum repolist`

Comment: @binarysta: first command did not add/update anything. 2nd command confirmed that the package is installed. 3rd command still does not list the epel. Thank you

Comment: even  "yum  --enablerepo=epel update" says: repository not found

Comment: Isn't the command `# yum-config-manager --enable epel` ?

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -qV epel-release`?  I suspect that even though the package is installed, someone has removed `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`.

Comment: I removed repel-release and installed it again but it did not fix the problem and even removed remi repository. So I installed remi repository again and /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo was created and things worked again.

Comment: @GracefulRestart exactly. Someone had removed the file and I thought I can fix it by reinstalling epel-release... But it wouldn't

Somehow installing remi repository created the file again.